# Subir múltiples imágenes y nombrarlas php

Tags: php, html5

Hola amigos tengo este código para subir datos al servidor.

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_FILES['imagen'])){
    $cantidad= count($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"]);

    for ($i=0; $i<$cantidad; $i++){
    //Comprobamos si el fichero es una imagen
    if ($_FILES['imagen']['type'][$i]=='image/png' || $_FILES['imagen']['type'][$i]=='image/jpeg'){

    //Subimos el fichero al servidor
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"][$i], $_FILES["imagen"]["name"][$i]);
    $validar=true;
    }
    else $validar=false;


}
}

?>
<form method="post" action="?" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="imagen[]" value="" multiple><br>

<input type="submit" value="Subir Imagen">
</form>


<?php if (isset($_FILES['imagen']) && $validar==true){ ?>
<?php $cantidad= count($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"]);

    for ($i=0; $i<$cantidad; $i++){?>
    <h1><?php echo $_FILES["imagen"]["name"][$i] ?></h1>
    <img src="<?php echo $_FILES["imagen"]["name"][$i] ?>" width="100">
    <?php}}?>
```

El cual funciona pero mi duda es como podría ponerle un nombre unico y que solo varié al final con la variable $i, osea "foto".$i.".jpg" por ejemplo. Es que para la ruta solo busco poner ese nombre y el $i para no guardar en base de datos. Gracias solo necesito saber como ponerles nombre ya que las guarda con el nombre original.

Comment: Sres ya pude resolver. :)

Comment: Ahora si alguien sabe, igual ando investigando limitar el numero de imágenes ya que no quiero sean mas de 3.

Comment: Si pudiste resolver el problema, escribe una respuesta y márcala como aceptada cuando pase el tiempo requerido. Y si tienes una pregunta nueva, publica una pregunta en lugar de poner un comentario en otra pregunta.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ya resolví Gracias. Bueno mas que resolver busque otra forma.